# How to sort a char**?

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting

I've an array of strings.
Unfortunately, the size of each string in the string array isn't constant so I can't do this:

```
qsort(fileList, noOfFiles, sizeof(*fileList), compare);
```

and make a custom compare function.
What can be an alternative?

fileList is a list of filenames. declared as: `char **fileList;`

The reason I can't do this is coz qsort is kinda a blind function.
 To find the next element, it just skips the said(third argument) memory units. blindly.
It results in random behaviour if variable length strings are used. As there's no way to identify the start and end memory locations of string by qsort.

qsort could be used for char *array[100].

Here's the buggy code as requested by many:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare(const void *string1, const void *string2){

    char *a = (char*)(string1);
    char *b = (char*)(string2);
    printf("comparing %s     AND    %s\n", a, b);
    return strcasecmp(a,b);
}


void sortListName(char **fileList, int noOfFiles){
    printf("Sorting\n");
    qsort(fileList, noOfFiles, sizeof(char*), compare); 
    return;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to note that `sizeof(*fileList)` is not the same thing as `strlen(*fileList)`.

Comment: *You* have to know the size of the array if all you have is a pointer to its first element.

Comment: @KerrekSB It looks like he does; the size of the array is the second argument, not the third. The problem that he has is that the sizes of the *elements* are not the same. That being said, it might just be a misunderstanding on his part; the array itself is holding pointers, which *are* the same size.

Comment: Umm?  Why can't you do that?  You are implementing 'compare', right?

Comment: Your "reason" is nonsense. The array consists of **pointers**, each of which is the same size.

Comment: In your code, change `strlen` to `sizeof`. That ought to fix it.

Comment: Per the edit: as you have been told **NUMEROUS** times, `strlen` is not the same as sizeof.

Comment: "qsort could be used for char *array[100]" -- and it can be used for `char**` -- the former decays to the latter when passed to qsort. Stop assuming that you know things about C when you're clearly a neophyte.

Comment: Now you've edited the buggy code so it *isn't* buggy? That's a no-no. Your first invocation of qsort already has the best usage: `sizeof(*fileList)`

Comment: From the png you posted below, you don't malloc enough space for filelist.

Comment: However, another problem is that the compare function is wrong ... I've posted an answer showing how to do it right.

Comment: @DennisMeng that doesn't fix it because the casts in the compare function are wrong ... my answer (and dave's answer) fixes it.

Comment: @JimBalter Hmm, you're right.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the number of elements, you can sort them whether each string is of same size or not.

define compare as:

```
    int compare(const void *a,const void *b)
    {
      const char *astr = (char*)a;
      const char *bstr = (char*)b;    
      return strcmp(astr,bstr);
    }
```

Comment: no this won't work for variable size strings. (I've tried already).
There's a reason why the third argument exists in qsort.

Comment: @BlueFlame If `fileList` is a `char **` (i.e. a pointer to `char *`s), wouldn't the size just be `sizeof(char*)`?

Comment: no, the size would be the size of the string element.
and that's variable.

Comment: @BlueFlame You're arguing with people who have done just this many many times and know full well what the third argument of qsort is for. The fact is, you're quite wrong: `sizeof(*filelist)` is `sizeof(char*)` which, of course, is constant.

Comment: @BlueFlame Again, I reiterate my very first comment. `sizeof(*fileList)` is not the same thing as `strlen(*fileList)`. `strlen(*fileList)` is the length of the string. `sizeof(*fileList)` is the amount of space the datatype takes up in memory (i.e. the size of *a pointer to a char*)

Comment: @BlueFlame 'no this won't work for variable size strings. (I've tried already)' -- It will work; I've done it numerous times in my 35 years of writing C. You made some other mistake. Consider posting the actual code that didn't work.

Comment: read the edited problem again...
 explained a bit there

code coming up in a min...

Comment: @Shamim Your types aren't quite right ... a, b must be const pointers, else you have UB, and astr and bstr ought to be also.

Comment: @BlueFlame Read your edits slowly, along with my last comment. You'll see exactly what we're trying to say. In `fileList`, the amount of memory each element takes up is `sizeof(char*)`, not the number of characters in the string.

Comment: @BlueFlame Your edit is irrelevant. Please, you don't know C very well ... listen to people who do. Do you know what "arrays decay to pointers" means?

Comment: @JimBalter Thanks for pointing that out. Corrected the code.

Comment: I would go whole hog and make the casts const too ... not that it matters.

Comment: I am aware am not an expert and I do appreciate your help.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33524466/result.png
here's my results...

Comment: @BlueFlame Sigh. Your malloc is wrong -- again, strlen is not appropriate here. I'll bet you're running on a 64-bit system, making `sizeof(char*) < strlen("forever")`. Next time, post a *complete* example of failing code, and stop assuming that you know where the problem is.

Comment: @BlueFlame The compare function above is wrong. See my answer for the correction.

Comment: I'd say **this answer's compare function wrong** as it irgnores one level of indirection. An array of pointers shall be sorted, so `qsort()`  passed down the addresses of the array elements that is `char**`, those need to dereference before the could be compared, which is missing in theis answer. The correct way how to do it is shown by *Jim Balters*'s and *dave*'s answer.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on how your structure is laid out in memory:

If you have `char **sort_this` which looks like this:

> | char * | char * | char *|...

Then you can easily sort this using qsort. You have an array of char *'s to sort. The length of this array is number of elements and the width of the elements is sizeof(char *). Your custom comparison function is also very simple: it's a wrapper around strcmp (you need a wrapper because you'll be passed the address of the char * and not the char *).

So

```
int compare (void *lhs, void *rhs)
{
        return strcmp(*(char **)lhs, *(char **)rhs)
}
```

If however you have a `char *sort this` laid out in memory like this:

> "This string is long\0", "short\0", "medium length\0", ...

Such that each string is continuous then you'll have to write your own sort routine. But it's going to be a nightmare to move strings around (swapping adjacent ones will be okay, so I'd go with bubble sort, it's also very easy to code and works well on already sorted lists).

But a better idea would be to rearrange the array to be pointers to char *'s and use the above method.

Comment: do you really need char** or char* should suffice?

Comment: No I don't have a pointer to a char, I have a pointer to a pointer of a char. The sizeof *(char **) is different to sizeof (*(char *)). So I think I need to do char **. That's the correct type of object that we are sorting .... so isn't it correct?

Comment: the method you're suggesting would work for char *sort_this[50]
 but fails here.

Comment: Show the code that puts the strings in to memory. One of my two memory layouts must be correct. So your "this doesn't work" can't be correct. One of these two answers must be correct.

Comment: @BlueFlame The method does not fail, *your* code fails because you wrongly use `strlen` as the third argument to qsort in that code ... contra what you originally posted, which used sizeof.

Comment: Dave, see the OP's edits. s/he doesn't understand that strlen and sizeof are not at all the same.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the correct implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare(const void* v1, const void* v2){

    const char* a = *(char**)v1;
    const char* b = *(char**)v2;
    printf("comparing %s     AND    %s\n", a, b);
    return strcasecmp(a,b);
}


void sortListName(char** fileList, int noOfFiles){
    printf("Sorting\n");
    qsort(fileList, noOfFiles, sizeof(*fileList), compare); 
}

int main(void){
    char** fileList = malloc(3 * sizeof *filelist);

    fileList[0] = "Hello";
    fileList[1] = "World";
    fileList[2] = "forever";
    sortListName(fileList, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: const void* v1    is same as    const void *v1.  right?

Comment: @BlueFlame yes, certainly, but many experienced programmers prefer the former because `*` is part of the type. If this answer works for you, please accept it.

Comment: No, actually `const void *v1` is better, because `int *a, b;` declares `a` as a pointer-to-int, whereas `b` is int.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala No, actually you're wrong. (See how that works?) It isn't wise to mix declarations for items with different types like that; declare each pointer separately. But hey, do what you want ... as I said, it's a *preference* of *many* (not all) experienced programmers ... I didn't foolishly go down the path of absolute claims. Now, is there some other minor off-topic subject that has nothing to do with the question or this answer that we can discuss?

Comment: This is the sole reason why it was written by many going together with the identifier in the first place, because of the rules of multivar declaration.

Comment: See also http://c-faq.com/decl/charstarws.html